Source for Quote: "The Best Propaganda is not Propaganda"
In the video shown here, Joseph Nye mentions the quote, "The best propaganda is not propaganda," at 3:46. He attributes it to "somebody", so I have no idea where he got it from. Googling the phrase gives another example where Nye repeats it, but it is clear that it is him quoting someone else. Some sources are attributing the phrase to Nye directly, but that seems incorrect given these two examples. Then again, this PDF  has a section attributed to Nye that states the phrase without quotation marks. Does anyone have a better idea on the origin?

IIRC during the Cold War, such channels like Voice of America and the BBC had the policy that the best way to influence the citizens of the Warsaw Bloc was to present news in a relatively un-propagandistic fashion, opting not to censor and sugarcoat Western news overmuch.  Might be the origin of the idea.  Might be a better fit for SE.History if so.
